# Alpha Blending With Apple UI on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to place an OpenGL view on top of a standard UIView with a UIImageView.  When I draw anything into the OpenGL view, I see slight alpha blending issues that result in the white lines seen below:
[image: white alpha blending]

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];
[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

[director setOpenGLView:glView];

if(![director enableRetinaDisplay:YES]) NSLog(@"Retina Display Not supported");
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[PPAvatarEditorScene scene]];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
[glView setOpaque:NO];
[avatarImage addSubview:glView];
```

I am using Cocos2D to draw into the OpenGL view.  Is there an issue with the Alpha Pixel Format or Texture Format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the glClearColor to black:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: It looks fine if I clear the alpha channel (glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);)

Comment: But clearing like you mention appears just like it does in the screenshot.  I am beginning to think it had more to do with how I draw it than any GL call or pixel format.

Comment: It's probably a GL State then (glEnable method).